# Trying to export all my products

Tags: magento-1.9, import, url, products, export

i am trying to export all my products and the URL so i can edit them and then import them back, but everytime i click export after about a minute i get a 500 Internal Server Error

Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

This is getting annoying as i use to have this problem with reindexing but fixed that by using SSH. Does anybody know of a way to either increase the connection time so it doesnt timeout or a script i can use to export the URL and all products and then re import. I found this online but after about 40 seconds it jsut goes to a white screen and nothing else happens.

http://t3jsot.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/magento-export-products-with-full-urls.html

thank you if you can help as it is very annoyign to not be able to quickly export and import data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `max_execution_time` is not too short in `.htaccess`, sounds like it is at the moment.

Comment: it is set to 999999

Comment: This will work if you have a small amount of product but i found i had to contact my server provider

Answer (score 0):

The way i had to get it to work was i contacted my serve supplier and they maxed out my limit. However i still have to export in small chunks as i have to many products.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1.
dont know how frequently you do database cleanup, but you could try getting rid of extra bloat before exporting logging into your database via phpMyAdmin.
1.select db
2.In the right frame, select the check box for the following tables:
  dataflow_batch_export
  dataflow_batch_import
3. with selected, empty

Idea 2.
in .htaccess increase PHP memory_limit to 512

Idea 3.
Probably should be first, but the others are so quick, might as well try them first. Enable MySQL logging http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/04/15/logging-database-queries-in-magento/ also check system.log and exception log under "mage-root-dir"/var/logs

Additionally...you could just split the job up into smaller chunks by exporting by category or sku or something in Export Filters section of Dataflow-Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :-

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 999999);

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

I had the same issue and it wasn't just max execution time it was memory limit. This will work but you have 4 ways you can add this.You can add it

- you htaccess
- your index.php
- your php.ini
- you can add this code directly to your export script which would be
  best since your setting would affect the rest of the of your program
  I do not recommend adding this global...

Comment: Not sure why this was hit down it works my issue wasnt just max execution time it was memory limit you can add it to your htaccess or your index or your php.ini how ever you see fit.